# Cluster "by part" instead of "as a whole"?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

**A definition before I start:**

A trajectory $t$ of length $n$ is here defined as a series of 2D coordinates $$\{(x_1,y_1), (x_2, y_2),..., (x_n, y_n)\}$$
Now I have a set comprised of such trajectories denoted by set $T=\{t_1, t_2,...,t_n\}$.

---

Take $t_1$ and $t_2$ as an example: let's say a segment of $t_1$ denoted by $S_{t_1}$ overlaps with a part of $t_2$ denoted by $S_{t_2}$. But for the other parts, they do not overlap.

All the trajectories may have such a "partially-overlapping" relationship with the others.

Obviously in this case, we cannot treat every trajectory as a whole, find a distance metric and finally cluster them. **We have to sort of cluster the trajectories by part instead of as a whole.**

Is there any already-existed clustering technique that does the job?

Any suggestions or pointers are very much welcomed.

Comment: Are those pairs of coordinates indexed by time? If so, are the time intervals and origin the same?

Comment: @chl  No, they are not. Time is not relevant here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest existing clustering technique I know of matching your description is:

[Lee et al., 2007] Jae-Gil Lee, Jiawei Han, and Kyu-Young Whang. Trajectory Clustering: A Partition-and-Group Framework.  In Proceedings of the 2007 ACM SIGMOD International Conference on Management of Data, pages 593–604, Beijing, China, June 2007.

From the abstract:

"Existing trajectory clustering algorithms group similar trajectories as a whole, thus discovering common trajectories.
Our key observation is that clustering trajectories as a whole
could miss common sub-trajectories."

I implemented this a few years ago and it works as advertised.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have also read and implemented this, whereas it fails to identify all the clusters. No matter how I tune my minLns and the other parameter, I always end up with fewer trajectories. Any ideas?